# Depletion Mode MOSFET Modelling in SPICE

Tags: mosfet, spice, depletion-region

Does anyone know how to model a depletion mode N channel MOSFET in spice?

I have looked online however the majority of resources have shown how to model a depletion **type** or enhancement **type**. I specifically want to model a FET that is fully on when there is a 0 Vgs voltage.

Resources i've looked at

- [A forum](http://www.edaboard.com/thread65979.html)
- [A help link](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/M_MOSFET.htm)

Comment: Can you explain the distinction you're making between "mode" and "type" in this context?

Comment: @DaveTweed In this context I am looking to model a fet where when Vgs is 0, current will flow freely between the drain and source. When Vgs > Vth the channel will close an only leakage will flow. Does that explain?

Comment: Can you give a link to the material you found about depletion "type" MOSFETs?

Comment: @ThePhoton the second one mentions depletion mode devices be I believe it's just referring to p channel fets. Also please tell me if there's a better nomenclature for these parts / behaviors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is given in the LTSpice help file you linked:

> VTO is positive (negative) for enhancement mode and negative (positive) for depletion mode N-channel (P-channel) devices.

For an NMOS FET, if `VTO` is positive, you have an enhancement mode device. If `VTO` is negative, then you have a depletion mode device.

For a depletion mode NMOS FET, with 0 V<sub>gs</sub> the channel will conduct. V<sub>gs</sub> must be pulled below 0 V in order to cut off the channel. In SPICE this behavior is represented by a negative threshold voltage, controlled by the `VTO` parameter.

From your comments, though, you want

> When Vgs > Vth the channel will close an only leakage will flow.

To get this behavior, you need a p-channel depletion mode MOSFET. An n-channel FET doesn't work this way.

Comment: I don't think you can buy a p-channel depletion mode MOSFET from anywhere, see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/704632/has-anyone-ever-obtained-a-p-channel-depletion-mode-power-mosfet