# Depletion-mode P-channel MOSFET availability?

Tags: mosfet, depletion-mode

I need a P-channel depletion-mode MOSFET for a circuit I'm building. However, there is no model available in [LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice) that I have found, nor is there any available that I have found to buy online.

How can I simulate this kind of MOSFET in LTspice, and where can I get one?

Comment: There was a [very similar question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150285/depletion-mode-mosfet-modelling-in-spice) asked before.

Comment: Also [this one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32528/where-are-the-depletion-pmos-transistors).

Comment: My fault. Didn't search thoroughly.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in the [LTSpice docs](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/M_MOSFET.htm):

> VTO is positive (negative) for enhancement mode and negative (positive) for depletion mode N-channel (P-channel) devices.

You can make a depleteion mode PMOS device by setting `VTO` positive in the .MODEL card.