# Has anyone ever obtained a P-Channel Depletion mode power mosfet?

Tags: mosfet, p-channel, depletion-mode

I cannot find any P-Channel Depletion mode mosfets at any supplier.

I see this question from 10+ years ago: [Where are the depletion PMOS transistors?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32528/where-are-the-depletion-pmos-transistors)

But has ANYONE been able to source a P-Channel Depletion mode mosfet for a power application (>2A current), or for that matter, any power or small signal depletion mode p-channel mosfets?

I am not looking for advice on WHERE to buy them, just advice on whether or not I should include them in a design. No point including them if they are not made by ANYONE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any, current or past.

For low currents you might be able to use a P-channel JFET, for example, the MMBFJ175LT1G has an Idss between 7 and 60mA with Vds = 15V.

Answer (score 8):

To the best of my knowledge, there are no commercially available P-channel depletion mode MOSFETs as a single device.

([Sometimes P-channel depletion devices may be found inside some analog and digital ICs.](https://www.aldinc.com/pdf/IntroDepletionModeMOSFET.pdf))